# WSO2 API Manager - ERROR - APIKeyMgtServiceComponent Error in initializing thrift transport

Tags: api, wso2, wso2-api-manager

Can anyone help me with this problem?
Some information
IP address was replaced for a fake one
there is no other service running in the server
MgtHostName and hostname are set o machine's IP
Running on AWS. 
Security groups allows AnyTraffic from anywhere (only for troubleshooting this)

```
[2015-11-02 03:52:46,251]  INFO - CarbonUIServiceComponent API Store Default Context : http://52.52.52.52:9763/store
[2015-11-02 03:52:46,465]  INFO - DefaultKeyValidationHandler org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.keymgt.handlers.DefaultKeyValidationHandler Initialised
[2015-11-02 03:52:46,465]  INFO - APIKeyValidationService Initialised KeyValidationHandler instance successfully
[2015-11-02 03:52:46,472] ERROR - APIKeyMgtServiceComponent Error in initializing thrift transport
org.apache.thrift.transport.TTransportException: Could not bind to port 10397
    at org.apache.thrift.transport.TSSLTransportFactory.createServer(TSSLTransportFactory.java:117)
    at org.apache.thrift.transport.TSSLTransportFactory.getServerSocket(TSSLTransportFactory.java:103)
    at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.keymgt.internal.APIKeyMgtServiceComponent.startThriftService(APIKeyMgtServiceComponent.java:211)
    at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.keymgt.internal.APIKeyMgtServiceComponent.activate(APIKeyMgtServiceComponent.java:89)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ServiceComponent.activate(ServiceComponent.java:260)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ServiceComponentProp.activate(ServiceComponentProp.java:146)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ServiceComponentProp.build(ServiceComponentProp.java:347)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.InstanceProcess.buildComponent(InstanceProcess.java:620)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.InstanceProcess.buildComponents(InstanceProcess.java:197)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.Resolver.getEligible(Resolver.java:343)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.SCRManager.serviceChanged(SCRManager.java:222)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.FilteredServiceListener.serviceChanged(FilteredServiceListener.java:107)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.dispatchEvent(BundleContextImpl.java:861)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:230)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.ListenerQueue.dispatchEventSynchronous(ListenerQueue.java:148)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistry.publishServiceEventPrivileged(ServiceRegistry.java:819)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistry.publishServiceEvent(ServiceRegistry.java:771)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistrationImpl.register(ServiceRegistrationImpl.java:130)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistry.registerService(ServiceRegistry.java:214)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.registerService(BundleContextImpl.java:433)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.registerService(BundleContextImpl.java:451)
    at org.wso2.carbon.identity.thrift.authentication.internal.ThriftAuthenticationServiceComponent.activate(ThriftAuthenticationServiceComponent.java:69)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ServiceComponent.activate(ServiceComponent.java:260)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ServiceComponentProp.activate(ServiceComponentProp.java:146)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ServiceComponentProp.build(ServiceComponentProp.java:347)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.InstanceProcess.buildComponent(InstanceProcess.java:620)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.InstanceProcess.buildComponents(InstanceProcess.java:197)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.Resolver.getEligible(Resolver.java:343)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.SCRManager.serviceChanged(SCRManager.java:222)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.FilteredServiceListener.serviceChanged(FilteredServiceListener.java:107)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.dispatchEvent(BundleContextImpl.java:861)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:230)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.ListenerQueue.dispatchEventSynchronous(ListenerQueue.java:148)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistry.publishServiceEventPrivileged(ServiceRegistry.java:819)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistry.publishServiceEvent(ServiceRegistry.java:771)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistrationImpl.register(ServiceRegistrationImpl.java:130)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistry.registerService(ServiceRegistry.java:214)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.registerService(BundleContextImpl.java:433)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.Activator.registerHttpService(Activator.java:81)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.Activator.addProxyServlet(Activator.java:60)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ProxyServlet.init(ProxyServlet.java:40)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.servlet.DelegationServlet.init(DelegationServlet.java:38)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1284)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1197)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1087)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:5229)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5516)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1575)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1565)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.net.BindException: Cannot assign requested address
     sun.security.ssl.SSLServerSocketFactoryImpl.createServerSocket(SSLServerSocketFactoryImpl.java:91)
    at org.apache.thrift.transport.TSSLTransportFactory.createServer(TSSLTransportFactory.java:109)
[2015-11-02 03:52:46,475] ERROR - APIKeyMgtServiceComponent Failed to initialize key management service.
java.lang.Exception: Error in initializing thrift transport
    at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.keymgt.internal.APIKeyMgtServiceComponent.startThriftService(APIKeyMgtServiceComponent.java:236)
    at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.keymgt.internal.APIKeyMgtServiceComponent.activate(APIKeyMgtServiceComponent.java:89)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
```

Comment: What do you mean by `Some information IP address was replaced for a fake one `?

Comment: I mean i changed my public ip for 52.52.52.52

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I did not find why i am getting this error.

I check firewall settings, port being used by another process and other stuff.

But i could solve the problem changing thrift server host on xml config file to point to my local ip instead of my public ip. (since i am running my machine on aws).

Answer (score 1):

The port should be occuip by another process. You need to find the process and stop it Or, You have to change the Thrift port number.

If you are doing the second option, here is the configurations.

The port offset specified earlier in carbon.xml does not affect the ports of the Thrift client and server because Thrift is run as a separate server within WSO2 servers. Therefore, you must change the Thrift ports separately using `<ThfirtClientPort>` and `<ThriftServerPort>` elements in the `<APIM_HOME>/repository/conf/api-manager.xml` file. For example, the following configuration sets an offset of 2 to the default Thrift port, which is 10397:

```
<!--
        Configurations related to enable thrift support for key-management related communication.
        If you want to switch back to Web Service Client, change the value of "KeyValidatorClientType" to "WSClient".
        In a distributed environment;
        -If you are at the Gateway node, you need to point "ThriftClientPort" value to the "ThriftServerPort" value given at KeyManager node.
        -If you need to start two API Manager instances in the same machine, you need to give different ports to "ThriftServerPort" value in two nodes.
        -ThriftServerHost - Allows to configure a hostname for the thrift server. It uses the carbon hostname by default.
        -->

        <KeyValidatorClientType>ThriftClient</KeyValidatorClientType>
        <ThriftClientPort>10399</ThriftClientPort>
        <ThriftClientConnectionTimeOut>10000</ThriftClientConnectionTimeOut>
        <ThriftServerPort>10399</ThriftServerPort>
    <!--ThriftServerHost>localhost</ThriftServerHost-->
    <EnableThriftServer>true</EnableThriftServer>
```

Comment: Hi, Abimaran, tks for helping. before posting this i checked that. There is no process running on the 10397 port. Anyway, i changed ports to 10399 to check and i got the same error.

Comment: Can you set the host and try within <!--ThriftServerHost>localhost</ThriftServerHost-->